# Calling SP from EF using same transaction of SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, objectcontext

Does someone knows how to call a StoredProc using the same transaction of an objectContext SaveChanges method (EntityFramework 5)?

The goal is to apply the objects changes and call a stored Proc that does some "magic" on the DB, but, if something goes wrong (either with the SaveChanges or with the SP execution) no changes would be committed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create the context
2. get the connection from the context
3. Create the transaction (TransactionScope)
4. Open the connection (will enlist the connection into the ambient transaction created in 3. and will prevent from closing the connection by the context)
5. Do SaveChanges()
6. Execute your stored procedure
7. Commit the transaction
8. Close the connection

Some code (MyContext is derived from DbContext):

```
using (var ctx = new MyContext())
{
    using (var trx = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var connection = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.Connection;
        try
        {
            ctx.Entities.Add(new MyEntity() { Number = 123 });
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyEntities VALUES(300)");
            trx.Complete();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like _that's_ an excuse :-)

Comment: I can't locate the ctx.Entities property in EF5

Comment: This is a DbSet property on my context (i.e. I created the context by deriving it from DbContext and created the `DbSet<MyEntity> Property...` on the derived context)

Comment: Everything looks perfect, BUT... does this work with Oracle same way? I think it escalates to DTC, is it correct?

Comment: I don't know Oracle. I think it depends on how they implemented this.

Comment: Any reason for casting as `IObjectContextAdapter` rather than just `ctx.Connection` ?

Comment: Probably that the former is also compatible with `DbContext` objects, while the latter is only valid for `ObjectContext`-derived entities, which is now the older approach.

Comment: @CrazyPyro - ctx is `DbContext`. I don't remember why I did not just use `ctx.Database.Connection` - would be shorter and should work as well.