# Database gets updated before SaveChanges is called in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to use EF with an insert stored procedure **as I have no direct access to the table**. My understanding is the database should not get updated until `SaveChanges()` is called in the code but database is updated everything an insert happens. In this case, 4 database calls were made.

How do I make this to have just one database call and update multiple records?

This may be classed as database-first EF? The stored procedure is imported as a function to edmx in a normal way.

Code sample:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        List<Product> products = new List<Product> {
            new Product() { Title = "coca cola", Description = "good"},
            new Product() { Title = "apple", Description = "fruit"},
            new Product() { Title = "orange", Description = "fruit"},
            new Product() { Title = "banana", Description = "my favourite"}
        };

        EFwithSPtest context = new EFwithSPtest();

        foreach(var p in products)
        {
            context.Insert(p.Title, p.Description);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]
@Title nvarchar (50),
@Description nvarchar (max)
AS
INSERT INTO [Product] (Title, Description) VALUES (@Title, @Description)
RETURN 0
```

Auto generated `DbContext` class:

```
public partial class EFwithSPtest : DbContext
{
    public EFwithSPtest()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }


    public virtual int Insert(string title, string description)
    {
        var titleParameter = title != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Title", title) :
            new ObjectParameter("Title", typeof(string));

        var descriptionParameter = description != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("Description", description) :
            new ObjectParameter("Description", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("Insert", titleParameter, descriptionParameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling SP from EF using same transaction of SaveChanges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593450/calling-sp-from-ef-using-same-transaction-of-savechanges). This is exactly your problem. `ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction` as such has its own transaction.

Comment: Just going to add this here: it's good practice to wrap your context in a `using` block. Won't change or solve the problem you are working on, but it's a good habit to have.

Comment: Thanks Both. Gert <- it seems like the question is similar but the solution doesn't seem to work with my situation. I don't have DbSet entities in my DbContext. All I imported from the database are stored procedures as functions. What do I do in my case?

Comment: The only trick is to wrap the calls in one TransactionScope. Calling SaveChanges isn't even necessary.

Comment: I don't know what to say now. It locks the table completely. I can't even find out if it is doing row by row insert or not. what is the performance implications on this (TransactionScope)?

Comment: I think you should not call the sproc directly, but use stored procedure mapping in the edmx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx