# EF5 - modify generated insert/update statement before SaveChanges()

Tags: entity-framework

I need to modify the generated SQL for insert/update operation, before it is sent to database. The required modification is very specific, so I was hoping that there is a way to simply append string to statement.

For example, SQL looks like this (Oracle BTW):

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
 SET DESCRIPTION = "ABC"
 WHERE OBJECTID = 1
```

But I want to append this line (in SET part) to update one more field:

```
SHAPE = sde.st_geometry('point (18 57)', 4326)
```

I can't add SHAPE column to EF model, because that is unsupported data type.

Now, is there a way I can modify EF generated SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

You could move this update to a simple stored procedure that is mapped into your entity data model.

Comment: Can I use stored procedure as part of transaction?

Comment: Looking at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593450/calling-sp-from-ef-using-same-transaction-of-savechanges - you can wrap the dbcontext operations, including the stored procedure call, in a TransactionScope.

Comment: EF6 supports using stored procedures for the Creat / Update / Delete statements. If you were to modify the stored procedures how you need them you wouldn't even know that it was using a sproc behind the scenes. If that doesn't work then you could use command interceptors which were also introduced in 6.

Comment: In most cases this would help, but I have a situation where I can't use TransactionScope. And because of that, I really need a solution, where I can modify SQL before SaveChanges and with EF5.

Comment: I think that if you make some changes to a table and then call the stored procedure, that would all be part of the built-in transaction that is committed during SaveChanges(). I'm not 100% on this, so please correct me if I'm wrong.